# How do you use sprays in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've been trying to hit the "T" key (also made sure it's the one designated as "Spray"), but nothing ever happens!

What am I doing wrong? Are there some prerequisite I need to fill?

Comment: Do you have a spray image already?  Have you installed it properly?

Comment: If you don't have a spray yet, you can't actually spray anything.

Comment: I have the default (purple black thingy). IS that not enough?

Comment: I don't actually use sprays (I have them disabled) but my guess is that default purple black checked pattern is not an actual sprayable image, so much as it is a pattern that indicates the *lack* of an image.

Comment: A checkerboard pattern is usually used to display a transparency. I suspect such is the case here.

Comment: Actually, the purple and black pattern is sprayable. I just tested it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order for sprays to work properly, you must:

- Have a spray image.  You can [download and install a premade one](http://www.gamesprays.com/sprays/team-fortress-2/), or [create your own](http://gamebanana.com/tuts/4488) by converting an image to VTF format.  (I'm not 100% sure if the default checkerboard pattern counts as an actual spray or not, and I can't currently test this)
- Have sprays turned on in the [multiplayer options](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Multiplayer_options).  I believe you must also allow custom content to be downloaded, although again, not 100% on that one.
- Be playing on a server that has sprays enabled.  Not all servers do, so if you can't see anyone's sprays, try a different server.
- Press the Spray key (default <kbd>T</kbd>) while pointing at a valid target.

If you're doing this right, you should hear a "spraycan" sound effect.  Some surfaces don't take sprays properly, although a flat floor or wall is usually safe.  You also have to be somewhat close to the surface in order to spray - too far away and you won't be able to.  There's also a cooldown between sprays, so you can't spam the spray button.

Comment: I'll try the detailed steps and report back. Thank you

Comment: The default pattern doesn't count as a spray.

Comment: I think the 'create your own' link is a little out of date- my spray is rectangular and I didn't need to convert it to a vtf file beforehand, I just chose it from the in-game menu, unless this is a new requirement

Comment: @Robotnik, you can import certain file types, but historically the best way is to convert it.  Some images/image types don't really convert as well as Valve maybe thinks they do :P

Comment: @agent86 - Ok, I must've just been lucky :D